# Quickly fill in cell array with numeric string

Tags: matlab

I would like to build a cell array of strings: `{'x_1', 'x_2', ..., 'x_n'}`. I know what `n` is ahead of time. Naively I might build this cell array as follows:

```
for i = 1:n
    myCell{i} = sprintf('x_%d', i);
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, i.e., a one-liner?

Comment: "A one-liner" would not be more elegant than your code above.  If efficiency is a concern, because of growing size of the cell array inside the for-loop, you can add `myCell = cell(1,n)` before the for-loop. See [Preallocating arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html#f8-793781)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is about three times faster than some of the answers provided:

```
%
n = 1000;
tic
myCell = cell(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    myCell{i} = sprintf('x_%d', i);
end
toc

tic
aCell = arrayfun(@(x){sprintf('x_%d',x)},1:n);
toc

tic
bCell = strcat('x_',cellstr(num2str((1:n)')));
toc

tic
cCell = strcat('x_',strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:n)'))));
toc



>> Elapsed time is 0.011541 seconds.
>> Elapsed time is 0.030992 seconds.
>> Elapsed time is 0.027931 seconds.
>> Elapsed time is 0.030453 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that a clear code that one can understand, like the one you wrote, is much better than a one-liner. But if you insist...

```
arrayfun(@(x){sprintf('x_%d',x)},1:n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way. You decide if it's clearer or not. ;)

```
strcat('x_',strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:n)'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `strtrim()` is necessary.  So slightly simpler:

```
strcat('x_',cellstr(num2str((1:n)')))
```

Comment: `strtrim` is necessary if the strings have to be valid MATLAB expressions: `strcat('x_',cellstr(num2str([1; 1000])))` gives `x_   1` and `x_1000`.  Notice the space in front of 1.